# Get facebook user groups names

Tags: swift, facebook-graph-api

I'm looking for a way to get the names (names only) for all the groups a user is a member of. I'm not looking for publishing permissions or anything tricky. All I found online is how to get the groups a user is an admin of.

***Edit***

After searching some more, this is what i've got:

```
func returnUserData() {
    let userRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: nil)
    userRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil) {
            // Process error
            print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
        } else {
            guard let data = result as? [String:Any] else {
                return
            }
            guard let userID = data["id"] else {
                return
            }

            let groupsRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "\(userID)/groups", parameters: ["fields":"name"])
            groupsRequest.start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil) {
                    // Process error
                    print("Error: \(error.debugDescription)")
                } else {
                    print("\(result.debugDescription)")
                }
            })
        }
    })
}
```

Thing is that it doesn't work. The error is not nil but the result is 0 which is not true.

Please help :)
Thanks

Comment: _“All I found online is how to get the groups a user is an admin of.”_ – that is all you can get.

Comment: Isn't there a way to only get the names of someones groups? I'm not looking to share, create, spam or whatever. Just want to know the names of public groups.

Comment: No, there is not.